# How to compare two .exes

Tags: .net, compare, analysis

I am working with a turn-around project for a company and suspect that the former CEO took a copy of the source to use as a jump-start for a knock-off of the product at a new company. If I can obtain a copy of the binary, are there any tools that could be used to look and see if I can find any "fingerprints" that match what I have?

The goal is to find a quick-and-dirty approach to compare the two .exes before turning up the heat and pursuing litigation. If I don't turn up any clear hits, then I probably won't spend valuable resources on getting injunctions and stuff like that.

Comment: [ildasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(v=vs.110).aspx) comes to mind.

Comment: just so you are aware, if they compiled with obfuscator then you are very likely not going to find any fingerprints even if they are almost identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JetBrains dotPeek is an excellent tool for looking at .Net assemblies. It's free too. You can download it from here. https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Comment: Thanks. That looks like a very useful tool.

Answer (score 1):

Another free one out there is [Telerik JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx)